# Can angular directive listen to hosts lifecycle hooks?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I want to create an angular directive that will be able to be on any host component and will make the host component background blink with green when the host's ngOnChange fires.

I have tried to get access(in the directive) to the hosts ngOnChange method through the viewContainerRef but couldn't find it.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[OnChangeBlink]'
})
export class OnChangeBlinkDirective{

  readonly green_color:string = '#27AE60'
  readonly white_color:string = '#FFFFFF'
  element_ref:ElementRef;

  doBlink(color: string):void {

    if(color){
      this.element_ref.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.green_color;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.element_ref.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.white_color;      
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { 

    this.element_ref = elRef;

    const component = vcRef['_data']['componentView']['component'];

    if (component.hasOwnProperty('ngDoCheck')){//never happens
      console.log(component['ngDoCheck']);
    }
  }
}
```

never fined the ngOnChange method, **maybe my all approach is wrong? how can I do it**?

Comment: I need to know why you're trying to do that to come up with an answer.

Comment: I Am trying to visualize the angular lifecycle by coloring the background of the component with different colors for each lifecycle hook.
I want it to be in a directive to be able to put it on any component.
thanks @LppEdd

Comment: For this to work you'd need every component you want to consider for this to extend an `abstract class`, and then inject that `abstract class` in the Directive.
If you don't want to do that by hand, you'd need a source code *Transformer*.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the abstract class is what i tried to avoid.

Comment: unfortunately the only thing you can consider is using a compiler Transformer to add that abstract class for you, in a transparent manner.